Declined "In need of moderator intervention" Flags - "link-only answer", "non-English content"
I often help when I find answers that I believe are incorrect or not entirely appropriate. I flag posts to the best of my ability. Recently, two of my flags were declined, but the answers I flagged were deleted.
What did I do wrong? I don't understand. I followed the instructions from this post: When to flag an answer as "not an answer", which had always been accepted before.
I'm not going to list every example, but here's one of my accepted flags where I left an additional note for the moderators:

2024-05-09 16:19 "not English" - HTML page content overlapping with footer
2024-06-02 14:35 "Link only answer" - Using HTML <audio> tag with google drive gives 403 Forbidden


And here are my most recent flags that keep getting declined, and I only receive a generic rejection message with no instructions on how to flag next time (even though the answers were deleted as a result of the flag...).

2024-08-27 17:25 "Non-English content" - can anyone explain how to make and arrange boxes using css?
2024-08-31 16:49 "Link only answer" - PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out on my local computer



Declined - Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags: see What is Flagging?

The explanation doesn't help at all. I've had flags declined before, and there were even times when a moderator explained that while they agreed with me, the answer didn't technically violate the rules, so it wasn't deleted. They clearly and politely let me know what I did wrong or right. But these recent cases are just confusing to me.
I'm not even sure if I'm posting this concern in the right place. I shrugged off the first one, but after the second, I felt frustrated, thinking, "I won't flag anything anymore..."

It's not me, but I think the mod just wanted to make you aware of the Not An Answer flag

Standard flags are all flags but the "In need of moderator intervention" with a custom message at the bottom, use one of these. They're relatively obviously neither of "Spam", "Rude or abusive" or "Plagiarized content", that leaves a single choice: "Not an answer"

Ah, forgot "Very Low Quality", which we don't use ever.

@Dharman I understand, but then why isn't that the reason given for the rejection? If they communicate with me, I can learn from it, but if I just receive a generic message to review the flags, I don't know what to make of it. Moreover, I thought that providing a personal note helps categorize exactly why the answer is "not an answer". Of course, if using the "not an answer" flag is sufficient, then I'll use it for both link-only and non-English answers.

@cafce25 I like 'very low quality' flags personally.

@CPlus well it's generally just taken to mean the exact same thing as NAA and handled the same way. You're free to use it, but I prefer to just always use NAA, which is always available even where VLQ is not, that way I don't have to think which of the two flags to use.

As a mod and as a normal user I hate VLQ flags

Unfortunately, we have limited ways to provide feedback. Users are not notified when they receive feedback on a flag. Many users flag so many questions and rarely look at their helpful flag history. A message on a decline action is the best way to communicate feedback because both (1) users who do look at their flag history are more likely to check on decline messages and (2) users who do not look at their flag history may eventually receive a flag rate-limit and be forced to review their declined flags.

Better visibility on flag feedback would greatly improve this, but we have to work with the tools we have. "In need of moderator intervention" flags can only be handled by the site moderation team. That's the 25 of us and we have thousands of flags already that need to be handled. The majority of "content moderation" can be handled by the community at varying privilege levels.

Flagging these posts as "not an answer" or "very low quality" push it to a review queue where the community is able to delete these posts. Using "standard flags" lets the community handle the things that it can, while taking some of the work load off of our site moderation team.

@HenryEcker Thank you for clarifying the answer to my question! It's completely clear! I will proceed this way in the future.

Moderators do end up handling a substantial percentage of the Not An Answer flags. An NAA flag can often be handled in a matter of a second or two, as most of them are quite obviously NAA, or not. For "in need of moderator intervention" (custom) flags, there's often a lot more involved. To handle each such custom flag can take anywhere from several seconds to a few minutes, to hours, days, weeks, or even months and involve the work of many people. Sometimes we know about what the time commitment will be for the flag, sometimes we don't.

For common issues that are covered by other "standard" flag types, having the issue come in as custom flags increases the amount of time that it takes to process them, even if all that's considered is the context switching that needs to happen in reading and evaluating the flag among all the others and then taking action. Thus, as the decline message that was provided to you says "Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them faster." Basically, using "standard" flags for the things they cover substantially reduces our workload, even for those not handled by the community.

"why isn't that the reason given for the rejection?" my feature request on MSE: Clarify what "standard flags" means on "What is Flagging?"

does "AI-generated" fall under "plagiarized"? when "plagiarized" showed up as a standard flag, I was confused. there never was much of any actual plagiarism. meanwhile, no standard flag for "AI-generated". why not? do you expect us to continue to use custom flags, or do you want us to intuit that "AI-generated" is supposed to go through the "plagiarism" flag? "AI-generated" content has no source URL, for one.

the VLQ flag is a trap. we are not supposed to flag VLQ answers. we are supposed to flag answers that are NAA, but the flag for that exists, and VLQ are treated like NAA, so the VLQ flag should just be removed. or preferably, VLQ returns as a valid flag for VLQ content that is meant to be flagged, but that's a different debate.

@ChristophRackwitz Interesting. IMHO it's NAA that feels like a trap and declined 99% of the time because just about anything that happens to land in the answer box can "look like an attempt to answer" if you tilt your head and squint hard enough. I feel like I tend to have more success using VLQ over the NAA flag. It's also a bit eye opening to hear that VLQ and NAA are effectively identical and for some reason handled not as standard flags, e.g. Mods stepping in and skipping the peer review part of them being sent to the review queues in the first place.

Why do you need more information from the moderator? They've already made you aware that you need to stop using the Needs Moderator Attention (NMA) flag and use the standard flags instead, which normal users can handle in the flag review queue. Moderators have enough to do already, and using NMA flags when they're not necessary adds additional work for them. The point is that you should use NMA ONLY when another flag doesn't already cover the situation. It should be used as a last resort, not a first choice. Not in English and Link Only Answer are not NMA-necessary reasons.

(continued) Not In English is one of the standard close reasons, and "Not An Answer* has its own flag. Why do you need a moderator to point that out to you in the denial reasons? Telling you to use standard flags should point you to where you need to read for yourself - the standard flags all have descriptions.

This question is similar to: When should I flag as "in need of moderator intervention"?. While the specific question there is slightly different (and from a time before "not in English" was a separate option) the answers there summarize the reasons why you don't want to flag for moderator attention when other flags will work.

VLQ as it is, is just an, I assume unintended, trap for people that want to flag everything that is low quality rather than downvoting it. Intended or unintended, it is misleading so I support every meta posts which suggests to remove it.

I would like to leave a small conclusion here from the perspective of time: It's misleading that I can't write down my observations related to the post when using the 'NAA' flag. So, I flag the issue with the 'NAA' flag, and then, in addition to me, three other people have to figure out what the problem with the answer is. It seems like the system works, as most of my flags prove to be useful; maybe I just wanted to be too 'precise' by writing down what exactly my issue with the answer is. Perhaps this could be a feature request for the future.
